# MATLAB - autocorrelation of unevenly spaced timeseries

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

In Matlab, I have an unevenly spaced timeseries described by a vector `y` and a vector `t`, together describing the value at points in time. The timeseries seems to be periodic. How can I determine the autocorrelation of this timeseries?

`xcorr` does not seem to provide the possibility to handle an unevenly spaced timeseries, and to my surprise I could not find much about it on google. Alternatively, I figured I might convert `y` to a regular spaced series using interpolation techniques, but I could not find a clearcut approach to that either. I feel there should be straight forward way to do this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK MATLAB does not have builtin functions for processing unevenly sampled data (although you might search more thoroughly the toolboxes or MATLAB central - see below).

Interpolation, despite the potential problems it can introduce when computing a spectral estimate, should be easy with

```
 xnew = linspace(min(x),max(x),N);
 ynew = interp1(x,y,xnew);
```

giving N regularly spaced data points {xnew, ynew} interpolated over your 1D data set.

There is a nice lengthy thread [here](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/41005) with details on various ways to obtain spectral estimates for unevenly sampled data. If you follow the advice in that thread, you will find a number of choices on how to compute the Lomb-Scargle periodogram
from [MATLAB central](http://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?search_submit=fileexchange&query=lomb%20periodogram&term=lomb%20periodogram). That might just do the trick but I have not tried it myself.

You can alternately try implementing autocorrelation on nonlinearly sampled data with methods such as those delineated in http://www.eckner.com/papers/unevenly_spaced_time_series_analysis.pdf

Comment: Hmm this also kind of answer my old question here : https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13838/mathematical-effect-of-reordering-samples-to-known-period-or-equivalent-time-sa